# how to save reserved data to register than push it to stack, clear that reserved data and than pop that data from register to print

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, nasm

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
   mov rcx, mesLen
   mov rbx, message
   mov rax, 0
   mov r8, 0

loop1: ; fill buffer
   mov dl, byte [rbx+rax]
   mov byte [buf+r8], dl  ; Use r8 as an index for the buffer
   inc rax
   inc r8
   cmp rax, rcx           ; Compare rax with rcx to check the end of the message
   jl loop1

   ; Save buf in rax
   mov rax, buf
   push rax
   ; Clear buffer, it clears buffer but then i can pop 
   call clearBuf

   ; Print the saved value in rax
   mov rax, 1
   mov rdi, 1
   pop rsi
   mov rdx, 8
   syscall

   call newLineFunc

   mov rax, 60
   xor rdi, rdi
   syscall

newLineFunc:
   mov rax, 1    
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, newLine
   mov rdx, 1
   syscall
   ret

clearBuf:
   dec r8
   mov byte [buf+r8], 0
   jnz clearBuf
   ret

section .data
   message db "42"
   mesLen equ $-message
   newLine db 10

section .bss
   buf resb 8
```

i'm trying to do that i said in title but smth is gone wrong. clear func is right i tested. it clears buffer. But when i try to manipulate with stack and call that func or execute it without call it dont pop value that i pushed into stack.

Comment: `mov rax, buf`/`push rax` only saves the address of the buffer on the stack. It will still point to the same place, so any changes you make to `buf` will apply. Your buffer happens to be 8 bytes so you could load that into `rax` but in general you can't push a buffer of arbitrary size onto the stack without looping (and is not a good idea anyway).

Comment: Ok. I want to make program that input string(of digits like"422 31") and program read every byte and places it to buffer(reserved data), then if next char isnt digit it pushes number from buffer to stack, clears buffer and start reading bytes again. Is it ok idea how to make this program or there is better way without reserved data

Comment: You don't need a separate buffer for processing. You might need a buffer for reading the string of course.

Comment: [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) shows an example of reserving some stack space for a buffer (for the opposite problem, of space to generate an output string)